# How to change UITableviewController Static cell section background color change using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to change the `UITableviewController` `static cell` header background color by using below code. I checked cell color, content view color clear and fixed tableview background color black, but section color not changing. How to fix it?

```
 self.tableView.backgroundColor =  .black
 self.mycell.backgroundColor =  .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableViewDelegate override the following to modify header view:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.tintColor = .green
}
```